# Alfresco: how to set default form value for a cm:person association

Tags: alfresco

I have an Alfresco workflow form with an association field that allow the selection of multiple users. The field UI definition is implicit (the model define the association).

I want to initialize that field with the current logged in user.

I've tried using a form filter and using `FieldUtils.makeAssociationField()` using the NodeRef as a value then `form.addField()` but this leads to an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Although I use the same technique to initialize a property field without trouble.

Can anyone point me to a workaround?

```
private void initInitatorNodeRef(final Form form)
    {

        final String userName = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser();

        if (userName != null)
        {
            final NodeRef person = personService.getPerson(userName);

            if (person != null)
            {

                final AssociationDefinition definition =
                    serviceRegistry.getDictionaryService().getAssociation(MywfModel.ASSOC_AUTHORS);

                final Field field =
                    FieldUtils.makeAssociationField(
                        definition, person, null, serviceRegistry.getNamespaceService(),
                        serviceRegistry.getDictionaryService());

                form.addField(field);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Person not found.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("UserName not found.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you attach the full trace for your exception along with your alfresco version!

Comment: There is no stacktrace. The FormUIGet webscript seems to catch and mask the exception. I'm currently testing on Enterprise 5.0.2

Comment: Could the reason be that you already have that association defined in your model, and you are adding a new association with the same name ?

Comment: Have you considered some other alternatives, like setting up the value on some ExecutionListener before getting to your task ?

Comment: So the workflow is not started yet as it's the first form, so no execution available. I thought about the association being already defined but didn't bother testing as it use to work for properties.

I'm gonna try that. Thanks for helping

Comment: >but this leads to an UnsupportedOperationException.
Any hint where exactly do you get that exception ? what line of which class is triggering that exception ?

Comment: Yes the `form.addData()` was throwing it on some Map.put call, for some reason in the context of a association the map of field data cannot be updated. I replaced the line above with the inner method `form.getFormData().addFieldData()` to force the `overwrite` parameter to true and it works. The association is correctly initialized now in my form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100501/discussion-between-yreg-and-plus).

Answer (score 0):

A [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740780/alfresco-how-to-set-default-form-value-for-a-cmperson-association#comment57244797_34740780) has been found:

> The `form.addData()` was throwing an exception on some Map.put call, for some reason in the context of an association, the map of field data cannot be updated. I replaced the line above with the inner method `form.getFormData().addFieldData()` to **force the overwrite parameter** to true and it works. The association is correctly initialized now in my form.